# gcc -c failed although it is linked to the needed libraries

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile, libraries

I wanted to make a `Makefile` for the program I am currently writing but I have a problem when it comes to compiling. Until now I have just include the source file into `main`  and compile it with:

```
gcc main.c -lcrypto -lssl
```

I am using openssl in my program. But as I read that this isn't good practice, I wanted to write a make file and just include the header files in `main`. But I have the following problem:

I want to first make the `.o` files:

```
gcc -lcrypto -lssl -c read_and_send.c
```

But for this one I get a lot of errors (unkown type name), the types that where defined in the OpenSSL library. I have no clue how to fix it as for using the math library I would write:

```
gcc -lm -c read_and_send.c
```

wouldn't I?

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Kind regards

Greenality

Comment: At compile time, you care about header files which would have declarations for library files you're using. So you need appropriate `-I...` options if they aren't already in the include path. At link time (no `-c`) then you use reference libraries for linking.

Comment: The `-c` option to gcc tells it not to invoke the linker, which means that the `-l...` options are meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for this one I get a lot of errors (unkown type name), the types that where defined in the openssl library.

You need to include the openssl headers in `read_and_send.c`

You should read a basic tutorial on C programming and how to use headers and how to compile and link.

> I have no clue how to fix it as for using the math library I would write:
>
> `gcc -lm -c read_and_send.c`
>
> wouldn't I?

No, the `-c` option means you only want to compile the source into a `.o` file, not link, so libraries are not used, and any `-l` options will be ignored.

You need to use the `-l` options when you link all the `.o` files together to create an executable. When you do that linking step, the libraries should be at the *end* of the command, after the files that depend on them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for anwsering. I have another question, would be nice if you could anwser this as well. I have seen some programs where they just include source files in there main file, this seems to be easier, why one shouldn't use this method?

Comment: @user3852496 keeping source files separate means that if one changes, you only have to recompile that source file, rather than recompiling everything. An extreme example would be the Linux kernel; kernel compilation can sometimes take more than 20-30 minutes, maybe even a few hours. If you're trying to make incremental changes to one file, it'd be **very** inefficient to have to recompile the whole kernel *just* for that one change.

Comment: Including source files in other source files is disgusting and bad practice. It violates the design principles of the language such as assuming that variables or functions declared `static` are not visible in other source files, and is just lazy and ugly too.